# Hibernate mapping-resource must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".'

Tags: xml, hibernate

I have a problem with mapping-resource in my hibernate.cfg.xml - I get

```
Element type "mapping-resource" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".'
```

my hibernate.cfg.xml  looks like

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"> 
<hibernate-configuration>

   <session-factory>
      <property name="datasourceName">java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS</property>
      <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <mapping-resource="com/mycompany/myapp/common/businessobjects/User.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping-resource="com/mycompany/myapp/common/businessobjects/Company.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping-    resource="com/mycompany/myapp/common/businessobjects/ServerSettings.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping-resource="com/mycompany/myapp/common/businessobjects/Station.hbm.xml"/>
   </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Not sure what the problem is?  Syntax seems right?  I'm basing my mapping-resource stuff on the info here

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html

Comment: Presumably the large whitespace in `mapping-____resource` happened when you were copying the XML over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misread the spec (see chapter 3.7). It needs to look like

```
<mapping resource="com/mycompany/myapp/common/businessobjects/User.hbm.xml"/>
```

You have a - (minus) in there where it should be a space. The xml tag is "mapping" the attribute is "resource"

Answer (score 1):

It's bad XML syntax. You're not allowed to write `<name="something"/>`; it must be `<name attrname="something"/>`. The XML parser is complaining because it doesn't find an attribute name before the `="`.

The documentation you link to does not mention `mapping-resource` at all, so it is difficult to say what the correct syntax to use would be. However, you might try

```
<mapping-resource>com/mycompany/myapp/common/businessobjects/User.hbm.xml</mapping-resource>
```

which has some chance of working. (At least it is well-formed XML, but whether it's the particular structure your tool expects I cannot say).